# Discord Bot Python mentioning

Tags: python, discord, bots, mention

I need a loop that mentions a user for x times in separate messages (x being random choice between 0 to 1000)
already tried this :

```
if message.content.startswith('$ZSEN'):
    await message.channel.send('MASZYNA LOSUJĄCA JEST PUSTA, I POSZŁO KURWA: ')
    for i in range(100):
        await message.channel.send(message.author.mention)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get a random number you have to use random library

use

```
random.randint(0, 1000)
```

for import the library `from random import randint`